# Java check string for comma and space

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String val` '6 000,00'.

I need to check if has space and comma.

Currently I use

```
String pattern = "([-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]+)";
if(val.matches(pattern)) {
  paraNew.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
  System.out.println("[Server - addDocxTableData() - Align RIGHT secondary]");
}
```

But it fails on a whitespace. Can anyone improve the above pattern?

P.S. I tried `"([-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]+[:space])"` it didn't work.

Comment: What is your objective here? You want to test if _a string HAS a comma and a space_?

Comment: This is for a Word document, here we have such standards for printed decimals

Comment: Checks if a string has numerical symbols, then align Apache POI XWPF Table row cell to the RIGHT, formatting

Comment: `([-+]?[0-9| ]*,[0-9]+)` will check for space AND a comma, but it's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve, i.e. what should match and what shouldn't.

Comment: see accepted answer for what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}(\s[0-9]{3})*?(,[0-9]+)??$
```

Validates a number if it has a space after every 3 characters (thousands spectator). If it has a comma (,) then ensures that there are digits after the comma.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGAyzZ/3/)

Works for:

```
6 000,00
9 000 000,50
3 000 000
630 000 000 000
940 000 000 000 000
-9 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

Comment: Congrats @degants - copying my solution earned you 15 points even though you managed to make it less effective ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it for you:

```
^([-+]?\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,[0-9]+)?)$
```

It allows the integer part to be any number of groups of three digits, space separated. (First group can be 1-3 digits.) This can optionally be followed by a decimal part with 1 or more digits.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/apevQk/4).

Comment: Would it work for a string with say 9 to 12 digits? How can I expand it?

Comment: Not sure how you mean. It'll work for any number of digits. Test it for what you want at regex101 (the link I included).

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[ ][0-9]{3})*(?:[,][0-9]+)?$
```

Will match

```
+1 123,12
-123 456 789,12456
12 345
```

But won't match

```
+1123,12
-123456789,123
-1234 56,123
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

so your regex gonna find this

```
1,111
+1,111
-1,111
1111
```

Your regex is not working because you are not checking for space.

```
([-+]?([0-9]*/s?)*,?[0-9]+)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need this regex: `^.*( .*,|,.* ).*$`

Explanation:

- Option 1: space comes first, then the comma. There can be anything between them: `.*,`
- Option 2: comma comes first, then the space. There can be anything between them: `,.*`
- Making sure one or the other thing matches: `(...|...)`
- You're using `String.matches()`. This tries to match against the full string. This is why we need `.*` to the beginning and to the end of the pattern.

You can play with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/G8RPnq/1).

Comment: This regex passes the requirements: _"I need to check if has space and comma"_. So whoever downvoted, please explain.